# how to get the rows from mysql that is-5 or +5 then the current row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL table. the column are ID, ChId, TotalView...

Suppose I want to get all the rows which have Totalview -5 then me to all +5 then me. I want to search in table for people who get similar views.

How I can write a query to get the all rows.

```
select * from test where test.chid = 1 and totalview are (-5 then current , +5 then current)
```

Comment: I think need a better explanation. Post your table schema, a expected result and what you tried

Comment: what are you calling -5 and +5? is the quantity of regitries that are before child 1 and after child 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this query

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE totalview> (current-5) AND totalview< (current+5);
```

Comment: `current` may not be a column in table

Comment: @Nitu Should I write a double query to check my channel.totalview. shivan is right. current is totalview.

Comment: ok, then you may first fetch the latest totalview, stored it in a variable and then fetch new record from the table.

select totalview from 
FROM  test 
ORDER BY  id DESC 

then store the record in variable $totalview

select * from test
where totalview>$totalview-5 AND totalview< $totalview+5

Comment: I thing you are right. I even don't need to do -5 +5 in sql. Thanks for help me

Comment: Its my pleasure to contribute in problem resolutions..:)

Comment: I can do -5 +5 then pass it to sql so I can achive all rows. Is their anyway to send only one. What I means is using inner query and search for all rows that have -5 or +5 view then my given channel. I means do -5 +5 for the channel and I can search all rows. Thanks again

Comment: You first need the current totalview data to run  the second query. And I dont think that there is any way to joint the current record as per your requirement from the same table.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from test where test.chid = 1 and totalview>=(current-5) AND totalview<=(current+5)
```

use your current totalview in current

Comment: current is not a field from OPs table.

Comment: i think OP's "current" means the `totalview` in the row.

Comment: yes@ShivanRaptor yes my means that totalview of my channel to people who have more then me just 5 totalview and people who got totalview -5 less then ,e

Comment: @SatishSharma Remember that I don't want to get the row which have chid = 1 because only my channel have id =1 (example). All other row have other channel id. Now I want to get all row related to my channelview +5 to -5. Is their anyway to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from test 
where test.chid = 1 
ORDER BY totalview ASC
LIMIT current-5, current+5
```

You should calculate "current-5" and "current+5"

Answer (score 0):

Use the query:

```
SELECT totalview as current_view FROM test WHERE chid = 1
```

Then substitute `current_view` from above query:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE totalview BETWEEN current_view - 5 AND current_view + 5
```

Assume this query `chid=1` returns 1 record.

Answer (score 0):

If we're doing this all inside of MySQL, we can create a temporary variable called @current, and then query on the result.

```
SELECT @current := totalview FROM test WHERE chid = 1;
SELECT id, chid, totalview FROM test WHERE totalview BETWEEN @current - 5 AND @current + 5;
```

Comment: I try to execute this. it's only gave me return totalview which is first query result. I tried to run all query but still have one column which came from first query

Comment: I thing to get it done through subquery. Please check it and try it.

Comment: How are you parsing the results? If you run both queries you'll get two results, but you shouldn't receive them as one table. And yes, we could also do this with sub-queries.

Answer (score 0):

get your currentview in a subquery and use it in the search criteria

```
SELECT * FROM test, (SELECT totalview AS currentview FROM test WHERE child =1) t1
WHERE (totalview <= ( currentview +5 )
```